# In js.class, is it possible to call other functions from the super class

Tags: javascript, oop, js.class

I'm using [js.class](http://jsclass.jcoglan.com/) and i want to be able to call functions of super class in the sub class. I know i can use `this.callSuper()` to call the current overridden function from the super class but what about calling other overridden functions?

For example in Java i can do this:

```
class SuperClass {
    void myMethod() {
        // Do something!
    }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    void myMethod() {
        // Do something else!
    }
    void anotherMethod() {
        super.myMethod(); // call the original myMethod form the SuperClass
    }
}
```

Is it possible in js.class?!

Answer (score 1):

You can make it without `js.class` if you know what `A` is super of `B`:

```
A = function (x) { this.x = x};
A.prototype.myMethod = function () {return this.x + 1};
B = function (x) { A.call(this,x)};
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.myMethod = function () {return this.x + 2};
B.prototype.anotherMethod = function () {return A.prototype.myMethod.call(this)};
```

If you don't know who is parent of B you can use `__proto__` where it supports:

```
B.prototype.anotherMethod = function () {this.__proto__.myMethod.call(this)};
```

If you really need `js.class` try this(checking this right now):

```
var A = new Class({
    extend: {
        inherited: function(childClass) {
            childClass.super = this.klass;
        }
    },
    initialize: function(x) {
        this.x = x;
    },

    myMethod: function() {
        return this.x + 1;
    }
});

var B = new Class(A, {
    initialize: function(x) {
        this.callSuper(x);
    },

    myMethod: function() {
        return this.x + 2;
    },
    anotherMethod: function () {
        return this.super.myMethod()
    }
});
```

Comment: I think i should use `this.__proto__.__proto__.myMethod`

Comment: I don't know why but the idea of using `this.klass` just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, with a little knowledge about how "classes" work in JavaScript.

**JavaScript Class Basics**

(you can skip this part if you already know this)

A "class" in JavaScript is really just a Function object that has a property called `prototype`. This `prototype` property provides that default instance methods and properties.

Let's take two example classes, `Point` and `Point3D`.

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Point.prototype = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    constructor: Point,

    isAbove: function(point) {
        return this.y > point.y;
    },

    isBelow: function(point) {
        return this.y < point.y;
    }
};
```

The `Point` class is our base class, representing an x and a y coordinate. The `Point3D` class inherits from `Point` and has a z coordinate (ignoring any mathematical inaccuracies).

```
function Point3D(x, y, z) {
    Point.call(this, x, y);
    this.z = z;
}

Point3D.prototype = new Point(0, 0);

Point3D.prototype.constructor = Point3D;

Point3D.prototype.isAbove = function(point) {
    return Point.prototype.isAbove.call(this, point);
};

Point3d.prototype.isDiagonal = function(point) {
    return Point.prototype.isAbove.call(this, point)
        && this.x > point.x;
};
```

In the `isDiagonal` method, we call the `isAbove` method on the Point class, even though Point3D implements its own version.

**Calling the Overridden Method**

You can call any overridden method on any class by using this basic template:

```
ClassName.prototype.method.call(this, arg1, arg2, ... argN);
```